# Replace character in string with another string?

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble replacing characters in a string.

Here's the code I currently have:

```
var entry_value = document.getElementById("entry_box").value;
var length = entry_value.length;

for(var l = 0; l < length; l += 1) {
    letter = encoded[l]
    encoded = entry_value.replace(letter, "b")
}
```

This will only replace the first instance of `letter` with `b`, my question is how do I replace every instance of `letter` throughout the string?

Comment: your code is invalid, try l < l.length

Comment: the variable 'length' is defined before the for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a global regular expression instead of a string as pattern:

```
"aaaa".replace("a", "b")   // "baaa"
"aaaa".replace(/a/g, "b")  // "bbbb"
```

Try this:

```
encoded = entry_value.replace(new RegExp(letter, "g"), "b")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do

```
entry_value = entry_value.split(letter).join("b");
```

For example,

```
var entry_value = "abcdcfchij";
entry_value = entry_value.split("c").join("b");
console.log(entry_value);     // abbdbfbhij
```